# GeoLocation HTML5 getCurrentLocation callback

Tags: html, geolocation

How to add a callback function to getCurrentLocation method passing coords or position as args to a global variable?. The object is allow to pass the coord to a global variable outside getCurrentLocation.

```
//Global scope
var Location= {coords:null;
} 

function getLocation(position)
{
  position.coords.latitude;
  Location.coords=coords.clone();
}

somewhere
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentLocation(getLocation, error)
Location.coords is NULL !
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Shoudn't be :

```
getCurrentPosition
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read all about how to use the geoloction API at http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/geolocation.html which is a fantastic site. By default getCurrentLocation takes a callback as an argument. The callback receives a position object.

Answer (score 0):

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentLocation(function(pos){
  console.log("I'm located at ",pos.coords.latitude,' and ',pos.coords.longitude);
});
```

Suggest using Paul Irish's shim as a fallback for older browsers too: https://gist.github.com/366184

Answer (score 0):

[Finding your position with Geolocation | HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/finding-your-position-with-geolocation/) should also help you out.

Answer (score 0):

In your code this row:

```
Location.coords=coords.clone();
```

uses a variable `coords` that isn't declared. The parameter to the function with the coordinate you have called `position`. Is it a typo?